# How to decode a string containing backslash-encoded Unicode characters?

Tags: go, escaping, unicode-escapes, rune

I have a string stored as `a`:

```
a := `M\u00fcnchen`
fmt.Println(a)  // prints "M\u00fcnchen"
b := "M\u00fcnchen"
fmt.Println(b)  // prints "München"
```

Is there a way I can convert `a` into `b` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`strconv.Unquote`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) for this:

```
u := `M\u00fcnchen`
s, err := strconv.Unquote(`"` + u + `"`)
if err != nil {
    // ..
}
fmt.Printf("%v\n", s)
```

Outputs:

```
München
```